# In place deserialization of packets in Rust

Tags: rust

In C, when performances are a concern, it's common to cast a buffer to a struct in order to deserialize it in place.

I've tried to do something similar in Rust:

```rust
use std::mem::{self, size_of};
use std::net::UdpSocket;

#[repr(C)]
struct Packet {
    foo: u16,
    bar: u16,
}

fn main() {
    if cfg!(target_endian = "big") {
        panic!("no implementation for big endian architectures");
    }

    let socket = UdpSocket::bind("127.0.0.1:1234").unwrap();

    let mut packet: Packet = unsafe { mem::zeroed() };
    let buf = &mut packet as *mut Packet as *mut [u8; size_of::<Packet>()];
    let buf = unsafe { &mut *buf };

    let recv_len = socket.recv(buf).unwrap();
    if recv_len < size_of::<Packet>() {
        panic!("unexpected packet size");
    }

    println!("{} {}", packet.foo, packet.bar);
}
```

It should work because I'm expecting to receive a little-endian packet and I'm checking endianness. I've also made sure that the struct is using C representation, and I check the size of the received packet.

The only thing bothering me is that, at the same time, I have access to the same data via two different mutable references: `packet` and `buf`. It's again Rust's aliasing rules so is it still OK to do that? I'm wondering if it's totally not OK because the compiler doesn't expect that, or if it's fine but we just have to be careful.

Comment: This is sound, as far as I can tell, but yeah you may not access `buf` after you've accessed `packet`. If you move the whole initialization logic into one block or a function, then it'll become inaccessible from the outer scope and you don't have to worry about it. Or you can assign it to `_`. [The docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.zeroed.html) also say that `MaybeUninit::zeroed().assume_init()` is preferable to `mem::zeroed()`, though there doesn't seem to be any particular reason for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unsafe gymnastics aren't necessary.  Using [`u16::from_le_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u16.html#method.from_le_bytes) is basically just a move instruction on little endian hardware, and LLVM will recognize that no data is actually changing shape and optimize appropriately.

Even at optimization level 1, these two functions have [the same generated assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/fYKM4qYx1):

```
pub fn example(packet: [u8; 4]) -> Packet {
    unsafe { std::mem::transmute(packet) }
}

pub fn example2(packet: [u8; 4]) -> Packet {
    Packet {
        foo: u16::from_le_bytes([packet[0], packet[1]]),
        bar: u16::from_le_bytes([packet[2], packet[3]]),
    }
}
```

At optimization level 2, [the optimizer merges the functions since it considers them identical](https://godbolt.org/z/8n7GhTj3o).

Comment: For this tiny example I agree, but when deserializing to a structure with hundreds of fields, doing it in place is simpler than writing hundreds of `from_le_byte` and hopping that the optimizer will take care of it

Comment: @Cl00e9ment I'd still consider generating that code with a macro and inspecting the output before reaching for `unsafe`. Note that you can define safe casts between byte arrays and types with [bytemuck](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/bytemuck/) as well, so if you want to go the direct transmutation route, I would strongly consider using that crate as the foundation.